# Is there a way to increase someone's bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Let's say I see a question with bounty of 100. I like that question. I want it answered. I'm willing to boost bounty with 50 of my own rep. Is there a way to do this? I guess not, so are there any chances for it to get implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed on MSO a few times.  The best read is probably, [More than one person should be able to offer a bounty for the same question at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64768).  Right now there is no way to do this (though I like the idea).

At the moment, the best option is to offer a bounty on the question after the first one expires.

Comment: How didn't I noticed it? Well, there is some truth to answers there.

Comment: Most questions and issues about functionality aren't really site specific.  There are some minor differences, but the software running all of the SE sites is essentially the same.  And, many of the issue like this have been discussed over on MSO, which serves both at the Meta for SO and as the Meta for the SE sites in general.